# Можно ли предложить пользователю включить backgroud-сервис?

Tags: android, android-service

Есть приложение у которого есть фоновый сервис (foreground).

Задача заключается в том чтобы проверить в приложении запущен ли сервис.

1) Можно ли как то узнать какое состояние сервиса в данный момент?

2) Если сервис выключен, можно ли предложить пользователю включить сервис, при этом перенаправив его на соответствующий экран настроек? (как на скриншоте)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте привязку к сервису, если привязка удачная значит существует, нет, то соответственно не существует.